# RegEx to find if string has first a character and then numbers

Tags: c#, regex

Can anyone tell me which pattern should I use for following string Format:

1. First character always 'C' or 'c'
2. After that 1-4 numeric Digits
3. Then '_'
4. At last again series of some characters (no. not fixed)

eg: `C10_COM`, `C1122_ABC etc`.

In c# for `Regex.IsMatch()`

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: hi Daniel.. I tried this \w\d{0,4}[^_]\d* ..  but never used regex. so just trying to get the right answer. I am not sure why I got -5 . :(

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is unlikely to help further visitors of the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
^[cC][0-9]{1,4}_.*$
```

Where:

```
^ = Start of the line
[cC] = either upper or lowercase c
[0-9]{1,4] = Match a number 1 to 4 times
_ = underscore
.* = Any number of characters
$ = end of line
```

Addendum: You didn't specify if you were allowed to have zero characters at the end of the line. If not, then replace `.*` with `?*`.

Comment: Many many thanks David for the solution and your explanation..it helped me to understand it in a far better way than in documents.

Comment: @LittleMissSunshine An explanation is always 1000x better than an answer. Give a man a fish...

Comment: Totally agree with you! Thanks again!

Comment: Concise yet detailed enough, +1 :)